# Merge standalone webapp and GAE in Go

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm working on a very simple web app, written in Go language.
I have a standalone version and now port it to GAE. It seems like there is very small changes, mainly concerning datastore API (in the standalone version I need just files).
I also need to include appengine packages and use init() instead of main().

Is there any simple way to merge both versions? As there is no preprocessor in Go, it seems like I must write a GAE-compatible API for the standalone version and use this mock module for standalone build and use real API for GAE version. But it sounds like an overkill to me.

Another problem is that GAE might be using older Go version (e.g. now recent Go release uses new template package, but GAE uses older one, and they are incompatible). So, is there any change to handle such differences at build time or on runtime?

Thanks,
Serge

**UPD:** Now GAE uses the same Go version (r60), as the stable standalone compiler, so the abstraction level is really simple now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In broad terms, use abstraction. Provide interfaces for persistence, and write two implementations for that, one based on the datastore, and one based on local files. Then, write a separate main/init module for each platform, which instantiates the appropriate persistence interface, and passes it to your main application to use.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate answer would be (if you want to maintain both GAE and non-GAE versions) that you use a reliable VCS which is good at merging (probably git or hg), and maintain separate branches for each version. The GAE API fits in reasonably well with Go, so there shouldn't be too many changes.

As for the issue of different versions, you should probably maintain code in the GAE version and use `gofix` (which is unfortunately one-way) to make a release-compatible version. The only place where this is likely to cause trouble is if you use the `template` package, which is in the process of being deprecated; if necessary you could include the new `template` package in your GAE bundle.

If you end up with GAE code which you don't want to run on Google's servers, you can also look into [AppScale](http://code.google.com/p/appscale/).

Comment: I really don't think that's a maintainable solution.

Comment: It depends a lot on how the original program was designed. It's worth remembering that GAE already *provides* an interface, which could be mimicked by OP's project.

Comment: I don't think it does - I think maintaining it like this would be more work than doing a fairly significant amount of rewriting, in the long run. And yes, App Engine provides the datastore interface - but implementing (even part of) that with a filesystem backend will be a lot more work than implementing a minimal interface that suits the application at hand, with multiple backends.